# HttpServletRequest.authenticate not asking for re-login

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

using the following code with the default configuration (HTTP Basic authentication + file realm in glassfish 3.1.2) as expected the client is asked for credentials. However, after a refresh or even on a new tab in the browser (even no cookies allowed, no passwords stored) the client is not asked anymore to re-enter the credentials. Only, when the browser is closed and re-opened will the client be asked again for the credentials. How is authenticate doing that?

```
public class AuthenticateServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            request.authenticate(response);
            out.println("Authenticate Successful");
        } finally {
            request.logout();
            out.close();
        }
    }

[...]

}
```

Regards,

Mike

-*Edit*-

The question came up while experimenting with the methods of using programmatic security. When using the following code in a restarted client browser a NPE is thrown by the first println statement. The login window doesn't even appear in the client browser. When, however, the println - statements are removed the login window does appear and the login works. When the println-statements are then added again (and no browser restart) they are printed. I tried as well to move the println-Statements into another try/catch - block but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
    try {
        request.authenticate(response);

        out.println("<p>Principal's name: " + request.getUserPrincipal().getName() + "</p>");     <== NPE
        out.println("<p>is that user in role 'gruppeA': " + request.isUserInRole("a_gruppe") + "</p>");
        out.println("<p>remote User is: " + request.getRemoteUser() + "</p>");
        out.println("Authenticate Successful");
    } catch (ServletException ex) {
        out.println("Login Failed with a ServletException." + ex.getMessage());
        return;
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
```

That lead me to the question on how authenticate is working and how I can use it. Possible, authenticate does memorize once a login happened from a browser and stores that info in the server. Possibly not.

I tried, btw, to invalidate the session. However, a new login is not necessary (which meets my original post where I - for a test - disabled cookies in the client browser).

Answer (score 1):

Authentication credentials are cached somewhere and it looks like it's based on the session. 
You could check for a way to clear the session in the server, but you could also bind some servlet at perhaps /clear and call request.getSession().invalidate()

I think it's pretty standard to cache credentials and sometimes browsers will also do this, what is your particular use case?